# How to copy single list attachment (as image) into the thumbnail/image column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, formula

I have SharePoint records in a list that are dynamically created with Power Automate.  Once the record is created in my SharePoint Online list, how can I say...

- Once the record is created, take the attachment value and copy it to the thumbnail column (Cover Photo) instantly so that the thumbnail has a visible image. (Is this possible today?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the new Image column or the Hyperlink or Picture column can be directly updated using flow.

A workaround is to use **Send HTTP request to SharePoint** action to update **Hyperlink or Picture** field.

Please see the references here: [Microsoft Flow – Update a Hyperlink or Picture field.](https://sharepains.com/2018/10/03/microsoft-flow-update-a-hyperlink-or-picture-field/)
/ [MS Flow and SharePoint Picture Columns: A Trick.](https://mikehatheway.com/2019/03/20/ms-flow-and-sharepoint-picture-columns/)

Comment: This saved me much.  I got it working on my end.  Many thanks!